Changing page fonts using hooks in class
I am trying to understand how to work with hooks in classes to change the font (size, color, etc.) for the first page of a chapter, and then switch to another style in the chapter pages following the first page. Hence, I have to hook to {cmd/chapter/before} in order to apply my style for the first page, but I am having a hard time figuring out what hook to use to catch when LaTeX does its first pagebreak. I tried {cmd/clearpage/after}, but according to report.cls, \chapter starts with a \clearpage, so the style for my first page gets overwritten. Here's a MWE class:
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{CustomReport}[2024/05/15 Custom report class]

\LoadClassWithOptions{report}
\RequirePackage[letterpaper, portrait]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\AddToHook {cmd/chapter/before}[.]{%
  
  %This part of the hook gets overwritten
  \color{red}%
  \fontsize{15}{24}\selectfont
  \parskip = 0.25in%
  
  \AddToHookNext{cmd/clearpage/after}{%
    \color{black}%
    \fontsize{10}{14}\selectfont
    \parskip = .5\baselineskip plus 2pt%
  }%
}%

Here's a sample document:
\documentclass{CustomReport}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}\label{s:First}
\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Second Chapter}\label{s:Second}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{Third Chapter}\label{s:Third}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}

How can I hook to the next pagebreak to change the style for the rest of the chapter?

The first page of a chapter uses the page style plain in the standard classes. So the best approach is to redefine that page style accordingly. Note that I have a horrible feeling it's my fault you're trying to do it this way ... https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/717228/. But there you wanted to change the colour of the pages, so you have to get the colour behind the content and that means you probably need to do it at ship out. But here you're trying to change the colour of the text, which is part of the content.

Could you explain what you actually want the code you show to do?

You can not change fonts or colour at an automatic page break as the text after the break has already been set. The page break can happen mid word in the middle of a paragraph, and the whole paragraph has already been set in the original font before line and page breaking happens

@cfr, yes I'm trying to change the style of the content and I realize I can't do that at shipout, nor using the page styles. This is why I created this MWE, to better understand how I can hook during content processing. What I am trying to achieve is a chapter divider page that contains the beginning of the chapter's content.

This is your class so there is no reason to use \AddToHook {cmd/chapter/before}  as you can simply define \chapter to have this code, there is no need to define it without the commands you need then use the command hook to patch in the missing settings.

You can not change fonts or colour at an automatic page break as the text after the break has already been set. The page break can happen mid word in the middle of a paragraph, and the whole paragraph has already been set in the original font before line and page breaking happens.

Could you elaborate a bit more? I think this is where I get it wrong on how the content gets processed. If I do this in the document, it works (but not in the class with hooks): \chapter{First Chapter}\label{s:First}
\color{red}
\fontsize{15}{22}\selectfont
\parskip = 0.25in%
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\color{black}%
\fontsize{10}{14}\selectfont
\parskip = .5\baselineskip plus 2pt%
\lipsum[2-10]

you can change fonts after a forced page break like \clearpage but (as far as I can tell) you are wanting the hooks to change the font wherever the page break on the first page happens to be. You can not do that and hooks are not appropriate here anyway as it is your class there is no need to hook into the \chapter command, you can simply define the command to do what you want. (but you can not change fonts at a page break) @drl

I see, but redefining \chapter doesn't change the fact that I can't change fonts at a page break (that was inserted by LaTeX). In order to do that, perhaps I need to define two new commands, such as \ChapterDivider and \ChapterContent, so that content is properly separated. Would that be the proper way of doing this?

Perhaps I should redefine \chapter with an optional argument that contains the content to be added on the divider page.

@drl essentially the only way of doing that, you can not change text width or fonts at an automatic page break. To be honest it is very rare to want that, do you really want to change font mid-word if it happens to hyphenate at a page break and fall on to the next page?

Indeed, that seems to be a bad idea to change font mid-word, which is why I think it is best to leave the option to the author on the content to be included on the divider page and break at the right place.

@drl if your divider is separating some kind of abstract or prolog for the chapter many classes have specific commands for that such as \setchapterpreamble  in the koma classes such as scrbook
